# How to web-scrape in for loop, without losing DOM? (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, dom

I`m trying to get data from polish Wiki-dictonary. Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kategoria:J%C4%99zyk_polski_-_rzeczowniki")
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-pages"]/div/div')
words = page.find_elements_by_tag_name('li') #loading all the words
delay = 30

for word in words:    
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-pages"]/a[2]')))    
    word.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click() #entering word
    #COLLECTING DATA    
    driver.back()
    # also tried with driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") - same reasult
    time.sleep(5) #added to make sure that time is not an obstacle
```

I get this error while trying to enter next word:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click you're changing the page which renders the previous elements stale.
So you need to either collect the pages you want to go to FIRST and step through them or you need to keep track of which element you're viewing and increment when you go back:

```
i = 0
for word in words:    
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-pages"]/a[2]')))    
    word.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[i].click() #entering word
    #COLLECTING DATA    
    driver.back()
    i++
    # also tried with driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") - same reasult
    time.sleep(5) #added to make sure that time is not an obstacle
```

But, as you can find in stack overflow, there are ways to launch the link in a NEW window, switch_to that window, grab the data, then close that window and proceed onto the next link element.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we are working with ahref tags we get their href values and then loop and driver.get() them.

```
driver.get("https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kategoria:J%C4%99zyk_polski_-_rzeczowniki")
ahrefs= [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-pages"]/div/div//li/a')]
for ahref in ahrefs:
    driver.get(ahref)
```